# Why Lasso classification results changes in Matlab?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, matlab, lasso

I am doing lasso classification using Lassoglm command in Matlab. I have a problem and that is, every time I run the program for my dataset I get different  variables to have non-zero coefficients. I don't know if there is something wrong with my dataset (like being small) or I am using some wrong Lasso parameters such as '**CV**', 'lambda' or 'alpha'! I have 15 X's with total number of 40 rows of data.

I already used the same procedure for another similar dataset (a 40x15 dataset with the same 15 X's, but slightly different values) using lassoglm with CV=10 alpha=1 and I get consistent results, but I don't know why for another similar dataset it doesn't give me consistent non-zero variables with logical coefficients!!

FYI, I haven not divided my dataset  into two train and test set because of having small dataset. I simply just need a prediction equation from my dataset using lasso.

Answer (score 1):

You are using cross validation to choose the optimal value for lambda.  Cross validation has randomness involved in where to make the splits of your data. So each time you run the program the splits will be different giving you possibly different values of lambda which in turn will give you a different model and different parameters with zero coefficients.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So what is the solution for that? Can I use **lassoglm** without using the **CV**? cause it seems in order to be able to get the **FitInfo** results such as **IndexMinDeviance** and **Index1SE** I need to use 'CV' in the Matlab command: _[L,FitInfo] = lassoglm(ZData,Y,'binomial','link','logit',**'CV',10**)_.



and In the case I have to use _CV_, do you think it is a good idea that in order to solve the problem of having different non-zero coefficient, I run the program for example 100 times to see which X's appeared most ?!

Comment: CV is there to find the optimal value for lambda, you don't have to use CV if you don't want to.  You instead could just input a value for lambda, then you would get the same results every time, but you would also most likely not pick the optimal lambda.  I think you should do some research on how LASSO works.